# Optimizing MySQL indexes for query (trading tick data database)

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing, create-table

My MySQL database has over 350 million rows, and is growing.  It's 32GB in size right now.  I am using SSD's and lots of RAM, but would like to seek advice to make sure I am using appropriate indexes.

```
CREATE TABLE `qcollector` (
  `key` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `instrument` char(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `last` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastsize` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `totvol` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bid` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `ask` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`key`),
  KEY `datetime_index` (`datetime`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

show index from qcollector;
+------------+------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+--    -----------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table      | Non_unique | Key_name       | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation |     Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+------------+------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| qcollector |          0 | PRIMARY        |            1 | key         | A         |   378866659 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| qcollector |          1 | datetime_index |            1 | datetime    | A         |    63144443 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+------------+------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+------    -------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.03 sec)

select * from qcollector order by datetime desc limit 1;
+-----------+------------+---------------------+---------+----------+---------+---------+--------+
| key       | instrument | datetime            | last    | lastsize | totvol  | bid     | ask    |
+-----------+------------+---------------------+---------+----------+---------+---------+--------+
| 389054487 | ES         | 2012-06-29 15:14:59 | 1358.25 |        2 | 2484771 | 1358.25 | 1358.5 |
+-----------+------------+---------------------+---------+----------+---------+---------+--------+
1 row in set (0.09 sec)
```

A typical query that is slow (full table scan, this query takes 3-4 minutes):

```
explain select date(datetime), count(lastsize) from qcollector where instrument = 'ES' and datetime > '2011-01-01' and time(datetime) between '15:16:00' and '15:29:00' group by date(datetime) order by date(datetime) desc;
+------+-------------+------------+------+----------------+------+---------+------+-----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys  | key  | key_len | ref  | rows      | Extra                                        |
+------+-------------+------------+------+----------------+------+---------+------+-----------+----------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | qcollector | ALL  | datetime_index | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 378866659 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+------+-------------+------------+------+----------------+------+---------+------+-----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple ideas for you to consider:

- A covering index (that is, an index that includes ALL of the columns referenced in the query) may help some. Such an index is going to require more disk (SSD?) space, but it will remove the necessity for MySQL to visit the data pages to lookup the values of the columns that aren't in the index.

  `ON qcollector (datetime,instrument,lastsize)`
  or

  `ON qcollector (instrument,datetime,lastsize)`
- Do you really need to exclude rows that have a NULL value for `lastsize` from the count? Could you return a count of all rows instead? If you could instead return `COUNT(1)` or `SUM(1)`, then the query wouldn't need to reference the `lastsize` column, so it wouldn't be needed in an index to make it a covering index.

  The `COUNT(lastsize)` expression is equivalent to `SUM(IF(lastsize IS NULL,0,1))`
- Do you need to return dates when there are only NULL `lastsize` values for the datetime range, or could all of the rows with a NULL `lastsize` be excluded?  That is, could you include a predicate like

  `AND lastsize IS NOT NULL`

in your query?

Those may help some.

---

I think the big problem is that the predicates on the `TIME(datetime)` expression are not sargable. That is, MySQL won't use an index range scan operation for those. The predicate on the bare `datetime` column is sargable... that's why the EXPLAIN is showing the datetime_index as a possible key.

And the other big problem is that the query is doing `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` operations on a derived expression, which is going to require MySQL to generate an intermediate result set (as a temporary MyISAM table), and then process that result set. And that can be a lot of heavy lifting when there are lots of rows to process.

---

As far as table changes, I would consider using separate DATE and TIME columns, and using a TIMESTAMP datatype in place of DATETIME (if you need to store the date and time together). I would rewrite the query to reference the bare DATE and bare TIME columns, and consider adding a covering index that included all columns referenced in the rewritten query, with leading columns being the columns with the highest cardinality (and having the most selective predicates in the query.)

Comment: If I add a covering index (say datetime, lastsize) [or the new proposed structure], but the query does not use one of those columns, will the index still be used?  Or do I need two separate indexes in that case?

Comment: Regarding using COUNT, I often use SUM instead - again usually within a specific time range

Comment: @user1530260: you want a single index with all of the columns.  Indexes on the separate columns won't help your query.  (They may be useful for other queries.) But for your query, you want a single index.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `date` and `time` functions on a column the indexes cannot be used efficiently. You could also store the date and time in separate columns and index those, though this will take up more storage space.

You may also want to consider adding multi-column indexes. An index on `(instrument, datetime)` would probably help you here.

Comment: Most queries use datetime between 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss' and 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss' (span just a day or two), so I found it much better to use a single column for datetime instead of two separate columns.  But some queries (like above) span months or years, and I need just certain times (hh:mm:ss) during each day to be included.

Comment: There are less than 10 'instruments', my understanding was that an index would not be helpful in that case.

Comment: If you want a query to be fast that spans years but selects only a few times each day, you need to index the times. In MySQL unfortunately the only way to do that is to create a new column because it [doesn't support functional indexes](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=4990).

Comment: Thanks.  What is funny (or not so much..) is I started out using two columns for date/time, but then decided it was inefficient so combined them.

Comment: @user1530260: we usually want the date and time together in a single column, when we want to retrieve rows from a contiguous datetime  range  e.g. `WHERE datetime >= '2012-07-14 08:00:00' AND datetime < '2012-07-14 17:00:00'`. In your case, you are handling the DATE and TIME portions separately, so separate columns is probably the way to go.  You are retrieving the same small time window on a whole bunch of days. For your query, your index should contain both columns.